# How to beat Early Stalkers (As Protoss) Help?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've been trying to win tournaments in sc2 but they keep killing me w/ early stalkers. @ 4 Minutes I get rekted by atleast 6 stalkers from the opposing team. I thought he cheated. Though I cant be certain. How do I counter this extremely large cheese ? I cannot get immortals or any Else out. Need help !

Answer (score 2):

You have prolly been hit by a variation of [**this**](https://www.reddit.com/r/allthingsprotoss/comments/7iqduu/build_of_the_week_pvp_heros_3gate_blink_all_in/). Just watch [**this**](https://youtu.be/zsbT5M3t9eQ?t=5624) replay. This is how you perfectly excecute this kind of 1 base all in.

**How can i be certain they have not cheated?**

> > Watch the replay.

**How do i know i am beeing cheesed?**

> > If they have not expanded after 32 food, you should start to worry. Its common to expand late in PvP but 32 is the mark. That being said, as you can see in the video i linked, you can also fake an expand. So you can never be too sure. If you manage to scout a busy twilight council, you can be certain a blink all in is coming.

**How do i scout it?**

> > Use adept shades or sentry hallucinations for scouting. A probe won't be able to scout it this late in the game.

**How do i defend**

> > Next to the units you can get out of your gates, you need to get shield batteries and immortals (so throw down a robo, but shield batteries first).

Last but not least, people cheese in order to avoid matchups (most people hate mirror matchups pvp zvz tvt) or because certain maps favor cheesing (Abiogenesis). So be on the lookout in these situations.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you are actively scouting your opponent.
I'm not a pro by any means, but if you scout and see that they haven't expanded after two gateways, then it's a sign that they're doing an all-in or some kind of aggression.
Keep your scouting probe alive to know when the timing of the attack is.
You could chronoboost your own stalkers or you could immediately place a robotics facility and try to chronoboost immortals as well.  Make sure to get shield batteries and defend at the top of a ramp if possible.  Focus fire injured stalkers while pulling back your own stalkers if they take too much damage.

check out all things protoss on reddit as well as spawningtool build orders.